# Request time out when pinging server on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ping

In order to check the health of a server I have, I want to write a function I can call in order to check whether my service is online.

I used command prompt to ping the IP address of the server, however all of the packets were lost due to request time outs.

I'm guessing I don't need to have a dedicated function related to handle being pinged, and I believe that it is due to the server security protocols denying the request. Currently the server only allows inbound traffic of HTTP requests, and I believe this to be the problem.

For an AWS instance, what protocol rule do I need to add in order to accept ping requests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Security Group for the EC2 instance you should allow inbound ICMP.

Comment: Specifically, `ICMP Echo Request`.